# Scale GameObject in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I increase / decrease the size of objects in Unity?

Example:

```
public GameObject sprite;
public  float scale = 2.0f;

void ScaleResolution()
{
    sprite = sprite*scale; //epic string!
}
```

Comment: They don't need to be public. Use [SerializeField].

Comment: @Jessy: [The Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html) actually recommends just keeping them public.

Comment: I don't see the recommendation.

Comment: @Jessy The first sentence is *"You will almost never need this"*...

Comment: That statement is incorrect; you will technically never need the SerializeField attribute, the same as you will never need private fields. However, this serialization behavior was designed for Uniy's "JavaScript", where the default access of a field is public, and there are no properties. If you're using C#, properties make it easy to avoid sacrificing your code quality by making all serialized fields public.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a property of the `transform` component

```
sprite.transform.localScale = new Vector3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f);
```

Answer (score 2):

Position, Rotation & Scale are properties of transform so you need to modify if as follows:

```
public GameObject sprite;

public float scale = 2.0f;

void ScaleResolution()

{

sprite.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scale, scale, scale);
}
```